# How can I remove Lync Web App Plug-in

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, lync

I'm trying to remove Lync Web App Plugin from add-remove programs, but when I try uninstall I get the following message:

> The feauture you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
> Click OK to try again or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package
> 'LWAPlugin64BitInstaller32[1].msi' in the box below
>
> C:\Users\212317078.R2.001\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary
> Internet Files\Content.IE5\0Q0XMQSY\

This probably because unavailable because I have problems with my profile. My %AppData%\Local folder is flushed/removed every time i Log in and log out.

Update: I was able to remove it from Add or Remove programs following this receipt http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314481 but the pop-up message still appears.

**How can I reinstall the Lync Web App plugin?**

Comment: You could try something like [IObit Uninstaller 4](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.php) (free) to completely uninstall lync then new install of lync as usual

Comment: @DavidPostill I am afraid that is not possible because we are not allowed to install anything on our company computers.

Comment: Then you should ask your IT department to fix up the mess.

Comment: Here is an updated link to MS [KB314481](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314481/how-to-manually-remove-programs-from-the-add-or-remove-programs-tool).

Comment: The iobituninstaller performs the same actions, as one would do manually according to KB314481. It does remove the Lync from the list of the 'installed programs', but it does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I checked the registry using regedit for every location of 'lync' and 'lwaplugin' strings, deleted all entries related to these. Afterwards, it was possible to reinstall the plugin using the standard installer.